# Что значит - Системы запросов в базах данных?

Tags: sql, база-данных

Что значит - Системы запросов в базах данных?
Может это имеется ввиду использование вложенных подзапросов?

Взял [тут](https://abit.knastu.ru/source/QUESTION_PHD/q_09_06_01__05_13_18__05_13_06_2017.pdf)

Comment: Список литературы не помог

Comment: Да может просто сам SQL язык имеется в виду?

Comment: Скорее всего, имеется ввиду СУБД

Answer (score 1, accepted):

18. Системы запросов в базах данных.

В данном вопросе спрашиваются про системы баз данных с реляционной (SQL) или нереляционной (NoSQL).

Реляционные базы данных используют структурированный язык запросов

Нереляционные базы данных, в свою очередь, предлагают динамическую структуру данных, которые могут храниться несколькими способами: ориентированно по колонкам, документо-ориентированно, в виде графов или на основе пар «ключ-значение».

Чуть подробней можно почитать [тут](https://tproger.ru/translations/sql-vs-nosql/)